# Android/Java obfuscation : R8 vs (ProGuard or DexGuard)?

Tags: java, android, proguard, dexguard, android-r8

I wonder what is the most powerful obfuscation tool (to avoid reverse engineering):

- between R8 and ProGuard
- between R8 and DexGuard

Thanks.

Comment: R8 is an APK minification tool, and it is not a goal to try to make the code difficult to reverse engineer. The term "obfuscation" is inherited from ProGuard, but internally in the code base the term "minification" is used.

Answer (score 8):

R8 is an APK minification tool, and it is not a goal to try to make the code difficult to reverse engineer. The term "obfuscation" is inherited from ProGuard, but internally in the code base the term "minification" is used.